# Image recognition in Windows Mobile 6.X

Tags: windows-mobile, opencv, image-recognition

Is it possible to do image recognition for a live stream of images coming from the camera/video camera on Windows Mobile 6.X platform using any open source CV libraries like OpenCv, EmguCV?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using opencv on windows and iphone are possible.

this link has a clear documentation of what you are looking for

http://alexkarpus.com/opencv/